# Mathematical logic - alternative of conjuncion AND

Tags: logic

I want to know if the word "also" do the same thing like "AND"?

For example, there's a statement like this:

`All the students who are good at Maths also work hard.`

Let M(x)  = "x is good at Maths"

W(x) = "x work hard"

To rewrite the statement, i don't know which one is correct.

1- `all students x, who is good at Maths AND works hard`

2- `all students x, who is good at Maths, then he/she works hard`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular example, it is number 2, an implication:
$$M(x)\Rightarrow W(x).$$

For all $x$ such that $M(x)$ it follows that $W(x)$. If they are good at math, then they (also) work hard.

"Also" in this usage should generally be the implication rather than AND - at least I can't think of a counterexample.

Comment: how about the statement "Some of the students who is good at Maths work hard" ? >> for some students x, M(x) AND W(x) ? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that seems right. If you mean that not all students who are good at math also work hard. In this case $M(x)\Rightarrow W(x)$ would not be true, because it would imply that all students who are good at math also work hard (but you are saying only some of them do).